About the Galois extension $K/F$, where $K=F[X]/(x^2-a)$.

In this example, we try to prove why $K/F$ is an Galois extension. I'm ok with the process of proof, the only problem I concerned is why we need to assume $\mathrm{char}(F)\neq 2.$

Ohh! I got it. Thank you very much!

@Smiley1000 This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

If $\operatorname{char}(F) = 2$, then we actually have $\sigma = \operatorname{id}$, so we might have $|\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)| = 1$.

In fact if $\sigma$ is any automorphism of $K/F$ then $\sigma(u) = u$, since $x^2 - a = (x - u)^2$, so $\mathrm{Aut}(K / F)$ is trivial.

@SeanEberhard I think you have some typo there with $a$ and $u$

I don't think so. In $K = F[u]$ (which has characteristic $2$) we have $(x-u)^2 = x^2 - u^2 = x^2 - a$. Therefore $u$ is the only root of $x^2 - a$ and so we must have $\sigma(u) = u$.

@SeanEberhard Thanks, got it.
